# WPF and winform integration, catch events

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

Short question:
How can I catch events in WPF application that have a win form panel that contains several controls (e.g buttons) and catch each button event?

And is it possible to add to the win form panel a WPF buttons and catch their events ?

I have a WPF application (Movie player).
It receive a winform control from 3rd party API (The video).
In order to play this control I need to use WindowsFormsHost.
If i want to catch events on the control, i have to register the event before adding the control to the WindowsFormsHost. But if i have panel with many controls, all the events are not catched..

What i want to achieve is that i could load a WPF stop/start buttons on the win form control.
Thanks[image]

Comment: Render WPF controls OVER a WindowsFormsHost it's really annoying, but you can do that. My suggestion is to render a WPF popup over the WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: But what is the proper way to catch its events? even if i make winform  panel with win form buttons, how can i catch each button event ?